# Navigation table float and width auto in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-tables

In a new web project we have a CSS problem, which occurs only in macOS Safari:
[www.health4hospitality.co.uk/template](http://www.health4hospitality.co.uk/template)

Firefox and Chrome (Win/Mac) as well as IE and Edge showing the navigation correctly.

On Safari the navigation shows underneath instead of right of the logo. It seems as the CSS table would be 100% width, but its width is set to auto.

Does anybody has a quick fix? I would be great if I would not have to change it heavily only because of Safari.

Comment: try adding vendor prefixes

Comment: For Safari it would be -webkit-, which would affect Chrome as well.

Comment: I use now (not extremely satisfied, but ok): 
`@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    ul.navbar-nav { width: 55%; }
}`
Thanky guys!

Answer (score 0):

I would set a % width for the `<ul>` nav bar. The `auto` property is rendering the element at 100% in Safari now. Setting this works for me across browsers:

```
ul.navbar-nav {
    width: 55%;
}
```